# QuickfixJ Performance Benchmark

Tags: java, benchmarking, quickfix, fix-protocol

Are there any recent performance benchmark results done on QuickFixJ ? I'm aware of the suite of performance tests available on the Quickfix C++ product, is there a java equivalent of it?

I know every use case is going to be different depending on the application workload and other factors like computing architecture used, loggers or message store used, message persistency and so on. But I'm sure somebody out there have done a baseline for things like 
the maximum number of concurrent sessions, orders or requests given a computing resource stack used and network bandwidth ?

We're planning to use JMeter to orchestrate our benchmark tests based on our own workload pattern. Any feedback on this, in terms of experiences with benchmarking tools and results will be very helpful.

Thanks very much!

Comment: http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2015/09/low-latency-fix-engine-in-java.html